# MySQL UNION ALL only returns one record from each table

Tags: mysql, union-all

The following returns only one record from the questions table and one from the discussion table. There are more than one in both of these tables.

How do I get it to return all the results?

```
SELECT d.discussion_id AS id, 
d.discussion_google_id AS user_id, 
d.discussion_title AS title, 
d.discussion_text AS text, 
d.discussion_views AS views, 
d.discussion_last_view_ip AS last_ip, 
d.discussion_created AS created, 
d.discussion_updated AS updated,
u.google_picture_link AS picture_link,
sum(v.vote_amount) AS votes_total
FROM discussions AS d
INNER JOIN google_users AS u
ON u.google_id = d.discussion_google_id
LEFT JOIN votes AS v
ON v.vote_discussion_id = d.discussion_id
WHERE d.discussion_deleted = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT q.question_id AS id, 
q.question_google_id AS user_id, 
q.question_title AS title, 
q.question_text AS text, 
q.question_views AS views, 
q.question_last_view_ip AS last_ip, 
q.question_created AS created, 
q.question_updated AS updated,
u.google_picture_link AS picture_link,
sum(v.vote_amount) AS votes_total
FROM questions AS q
INNER JOIN google_users AS u
ON u.google_id = q.question_google_id
LEFT JOIN votes AS v
ON v.vote_question_id = q.question_id
WHERE q.question_deleted = 0
ORDER BY votes_total
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use normal columns and aggregate functions in a select, you should use a GROUP BY clause, otherwise MySQL returns only the first row.

Comment: It returns a row. Yes, it happens to be the 'first' one, but this behaviour is not guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, yhe "first row" means whatever row the db server chooses to return based on the query. This is actually a bit silly feature of MySQL. IMHO, in 99% of cases the use of normal columns combined with aggregate function without the GROUP BY, user would be better served if the DB would return an error or it would automatically add the GROUP BY as it already knows what the GROUP BY should be (all the normal columns).